# Socket.io : How to exclude Flashsocket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io 0.9.16 to send notifications to my users.

Everything is working fine, expect for Firefox (version 47). This browser is obviously using the Flashsocket callback and display a nasty warning :

> "Firefox has prevented the outdated plugin "Adobe Flash" from running..."

1) Why the last version of Firefox is using Flashsocket as a callback, and not websocket ?

2) I don't want to use Flash at all. I tried to disable Flashsocket by setting which transports I want to use:

**Client JS :**

```
 var socket = io.connect('myIP:XXXX',
 {transports : ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "htmlfile", "jsonp-polling"]});
```

**Server JS :**

```
  var io = require('/Path/TO/socket.io').listen(XXXX);

  io.configure(function () {  
  io.set("transports", ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "htmlfile", "jsonp-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
  });
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  etc...
```

But what I did above is not working. Firefox continues to use Flash and shows the warning (as Chrome is using websocket all right)

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

PS : I know socket.io v1.x is not using Flash as a callback anymore so it would be solution to upgrade, but I can't just figure out how to adapt my script to make it work with the v1.x version, so I'd like to stay with v0.9.16 if it possible.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: v0.9.16 is pretty old.  It may be difficult to find many people here who could advise you on it any more.

Comment: Yes indeed that's a problem. Worst case scenario I'll try to convert my old script for socket.io v1.x

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but updating version of socket.io and node solved the problem. Sample code given below:

**Client JS**

```
socket = io.connect('ip:port', {transports : ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "htmlfile", "jsonp-polling"]});
```

**Server JS**

```
var http = require('http');
//creating server
var server = new http.createServer();
//setting server listening port and domain
server.listen(PORT, DOMAIN);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {transports: ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "htmlfile", "jsonp-polling"]});
```